# Can my daughter's iPad mini upload photos to Photo Stream without downloading photos from my devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, photo-stream

I just bought my daughter an iPad mini for her birthday, and I have everything set up with iCloud like mine, because if she takes a picture, I want it to show up in my photo stream so that I see what she's taking pictures of. But - I don't want all of my pictures to go into her photo stream. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Enabling *My Photo Stream* to allow photos to be uploaded to the Photo Stream also enables downloading of the Photo Stream to the device.